# Server side Swift : Error when push to heroku

Tags: swift, server-side-swift

I have a problem when i push it to master

remote: -----> Swift app detected

remote: fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)

remote: Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM 
not set).

remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Swift app.

remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to test-vapor-herokus.
remote:

PLEASE help me fix it

Comment: Please, provide more specific details on what you have done (commands, etc.) and how have you tried to fix it.

Comment: you should talk to heroku support

Comment: FWIW. I've had the similar error message for my python/django app, which was triggered by a 3rd party module poorly setup.